# Submitting a form with JQuery on page load

Tags: jquery, html, forms, certificate-authority

I've a 'User Certificate' form on my Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Server. 
The form is hosted on the URL:

```
 https://mycaserver/certsrv/certrqbi.asp?type=0.
```

The simplified html for this form is:

```
<html>
<body>
<Form Name=SubmittedData Action="certfnsh.asp" OnSubmit="return goNext();" Method=Post>
    <Input Type=Hidden Name=Mode>             <!-- used in request ('newreq'|'chkpnd') -->
    <Input Type=Hidden Name=CertAttrib>       <!-- used in request -->
    <Input Type=Hidden Name=FriendlyType>     <!-- used on pending -->
    <TR><TD></TD>
        <TD ID=locSubmitAlign Align=Right>
        <Input ID=locBtnSubmit Type=Submit Name=btnSubmit Value="Submit &gt;" >
    </TD></TR>
</Table>
</Form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to:

- Use Jquery to load the URL for html page above and auto click the submit button.
- Then after clicking submit examine the response to search for a substring.

Can someone please give me some pointers?

Thanks very much

Comment: If you load the url with jQuery (assuming CORS is enabled) the form's action will no longer point to the right location, unless your server also has that action. You could again do a CORS POST to the desired action though.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a start point

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form[name="SubmittedData"]').unbind().on('submit', function(){
    var t = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type : t.attr( 'method' ),
      url : t.attr( 'action' ),
      data : t.serialize(),
      success : function( d ){
        //Check the result in firebug (chrome developer tools) console
        console.log( d );
        // do rest of stuff after submitting for is ok
        //alert( d ); //use this if you do not have firebug
      },
      error : function(xhr, opts, error){
        console.log( error );
      }
    });
  }).trigger( 'submit' );
});
```

I do not understand the second point, what you exactly need. Maybe after you are show us what you get at "success" step we can play with the rest of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ajax post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send your form and examine the result. Put an id 'SubmittedData' on the form to make things easier,

Also, you should be loading this when JQuery is loaded, rather than when the page is loaded (small difference there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('certfnsh.asp', $("#SubmittedData").serialize(), function(data) {
       alert(data);
    });
});
```